# Keras model having multiple inputs causes strange errors when fitting

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am currently working on a encoder-decoder model using GRUs. It takes 2 inputs, encoder input and decoder input. There is only one output from the decoder. The model is:

```
encoder=tf.keras.layers.GRU(10,return_state=True)
_,state=encoder(encoder_input)

decoder_input=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,10))
decoder=tf.keras.layers.GRU(10,return_sequences=True)
decoder_output=decoder(decoder_input,initial_state=state)

model=tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[encoder_input,decoder_input],outputs=decoder_output)

model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss='MeanSquaredError',metrics=['Accuracy'])
```

When I try to fit the model with the following pseudocode: `model.fit(x=[encoder_data,decoder_data],y=decoder_truth)`, `encoder_data`, `decoder_data` and `decoder_truth` all being nested lists of lists and having shape `(None,None,10)`, and `decoder_data` and `decoder_truth` having the same shape

The code raises: `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decoder_data and decoder_truth should be the same length as GRUs give one output for each input. Also, the number of time steps per batch should remain constant.